# WearableDrawerLayout.DrawerStateCallback's onDrawerClosed not being called (but onDrawerOpened is)

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os, drawerlayout

I'm building a standalone application for Wear OS. My issue is that the `WearableDrawerLayout.DrawerStateCallback`'s `onDrawerClosed()` is never called. Thus, when the user toggles some settings in the drawer and then closes the drawer, the changes are NOT reflected on the active fragment (`MainFragment`). (Also, the active fragment on screen does NOT call `onResume()` when I swipe the `WearableDrawerView` closed, so that workaround is not an option.)

The following is my layout for `MainActivity`. Both the `main_content` and `drawer_content` are Fragments. For the sake of my question let's call them `MainFragment` and `DrawerFragment`, respectively.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/main_content" />

    <androidx.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_action_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/overlay_background"
        app:drawerContent="@+id/drawer_content"
        app:peekView="@+id/peek_view">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/peek_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_peek_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/action_drawer_peek_top_padding">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/peek_view_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/peek_view_icon_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_drawer_expand_icon_top_margin"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_less_white_22" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerView>

</androidx.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout>
```

In my MainActivity I implement `DrawerCallback.DrawerCallbackListener` and programmatically set my custom implementation of `DrawerStateCallback`, a class called `DrawerCallback`.

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), DrawerCallback.DrawerCallbackListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // some initialization stuff
        ...

        mWearableDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        mWearableDrawerLayout.setDrawerStateCallback(DrawerCallback(this))
        mWearableActionDrawer =
            findViewById<WearableDrawerView>(R.id.bottom_action_drawer).apply {
                // Peeks action drawer on the bottom.
                controller.peekDrawer()
            }
    }
}
```

```
class DrawerCallback(private val listener: DrawerCallbackListener) :
    WearableDrawerLayout.DrawerStateCallback() {

    override fun onDrawerStateChanged(layout: WearableDrawerLayout?, newState: Int) {
        super.onDrawerStateChanged(layout, newState)

        Log.d("onDrawerStateChanged")
    }

    override fun onDrawerClosed(layout: WearableDrawerLayout?, drawerView: WearableDrawerView?) {
        super.onDrawerClosed(layout, drawerView)

        Log.d("onDrawerClosed") // TODO: WHY IS THIS LINE NEVER GETTING HIT??

        listener.onDrawerClosed()
    }

    override fun onDrawerOpened(layout: WearableDrawerLayout?, drawerView: WearableDrawerView?) {
        super.onDrawerOpened(layout, drawerView)

        Log.d("onDrawerOpened")

        listener.onDrawerOpened()
    }

    interface DrawerCallbackListener {
        fun onDrawerClosed()

        fun onDrawerOpened()
    }
}
```

While `onDrawerOpened()` IS called when the drawer is opened, `onDrawerClosed()` is NOT called when the drawer is closed. `onDrawerStateChanged()` is also being called but the `newState` integer only represents its current state of motion (idle, dragging, or settling).

How can I get `MainFragment` to recognize changes made in `DrawerFragment` to some settings values such as `colorScheme` and update its UI accordingly? The values of the settings, like `colorScheme`, are stored / shared between the fragments via `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I was able to reflect the changes to settings in `MainFragment` by creating a new instance of it and replacing it using a fragment transaction when a change was detected in the data.

This worked because on fragment initialization is when the view pulls from the settings to determine what it should look like. Although this workaround will not work if there are values in either fragment that I would need to hold onto.